# Swift- How to set TableView separator insets edge-to-edge and have layout margins

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to set the separators of my table view to be edge-to-edge by using

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

But I want to adjust the layout margins so that the content of the cells have right and left margins of 20 (instead of the default 15) with

```
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
```

but the layout margins won't apply unless I remove the separator edge insets.

How do I use both at the same time?

Comment: Why don't you use autolayout constraints instead to adjust your UI?

Comment: If I do that, I won’t be able to make my separators edge to edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything and nothing seemed to work. This is what I ended up doing:

I added a UIView with a height of 0.5 to the bottom of the cell in my storyboard. I also added constraints to make it edge-to-edge. Then I set the `separatorStyle` of the tableView to `.none`

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your storyboard and click on the specific cell(s) that you would like to change the separator edge insets, then go to the right where the attributes and look for 'separator inset' and click it so you get custom and enter it there

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCIn2.png)

Comment: I want my separators to be edge-to-edge. I want my content to have an inset of 20 (which is made through layout margins, but my issue is that you can have edge-to-edge separators and have a custom inset for only the content of the cell)

Comment: @tajhespitz I'm sorry what is your issue then? I don't understand what your issue is, can you clarify?

Comment: I want to have a custom inset for my cell’s content. For example, I want the label to have a 30pt inset from the left. At the same time, I want my separators to be edge-to-edge with no inset. I can’t figure out how to do that. I can set the layout margins to 30pt, but the separators must also have an inset of 30pt. If i make the separators edge to edge, my layout margins for the content won’t apply.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the UITableView and In the Attributes Inspector there is property Separator Inset, choose **custom** now set 20 on both fields.

Comment: I want my separators to be edge-to-edge, If I use this, it will add an inset to the separators. I want my content to have an inset of 20 (which is made through layout margins, but my issue is that you can have edge-to-edge separators and have a custom inset for only the content of the cell)